# How to exclude the Rust std env when play substrate code in IDE

Tags: rust, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, substrate

I use the JetBrains IDE with a Rust plugin to run the code of Substrate.

The Substrate project usually has a line on top of a file:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
```

However, this line is gray, now bright yellow, this line is not activated, the cfg attribute is not using now. which means the development env is still in Rust std env, I guess.

Substrate doesn't use the Rust std lib. So, I wondering is it possible to config the IDE to activate the substrate std env, but not the Rust std. This maybe useful for beginner not to include some incorrect func or lib.

Comment: You might be able to do this by going into Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Rust -> Cargo, then unchecking "Compile all project targets if possible". If that doesn't work, selecting "Run external linter to analyze code on the fly" probably will at the cost of being a bit slower and maybe losing some other features. The location might be a little different for Intellij since I am referring to where the option is located in CLion.

Answer (score 0):

> Substrate doesn't use the Rust std lib.

This is not right, we just use the normal `std` when compiling for native. Aka when you compile the node. However, when we compile for `wasm` we disable `std` and use `no_std`.

As we have `std` enabled always by default, the IDE will almost never have `no_std` activated. So, I would just ignore this "warning".

Comment: Yes, you're right. I googled for serval days. I still not understand how or which part code is built into wasm.